# Json Schema - validate pattern for string inside an array is ignored

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a schema defined this way:

```
"permissions": {
          "type": "array",
            "properties": {
               "items":
                 {
                   "$ref": "#/definitions/permissionsType"
                 }
            }
        },
```

and permissionsType:

```
"permissionsType": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+$"
    },
```

...

I am not sure why the pattern regex is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `properties` keyword and it will work as expected.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `properties` keyword here. `properties` only applies when the instance being validated is an object. Because the instance is an array, `properties` is ignored. If the instance were an object, the `properties` keyword would apply, but it would be expecting an object with a property name `"items"` that matches `#/definitions/permissionsType`. I don't think that's what you meant. I think you wanted an array whose items all match  `#/definitions/permissionsType`.

```
"permissions": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/permissionsType" }
}
```